# Where is the best place for authentication check in angular?

Tags: angularjs, authentication, angular-ui-router

In building an Angular app where you must be logged in to see any page, where is the best place to put auth checks? I have always put a check in app.run under $stateChangeStart, but I 'm seeing some people use UI-router and resolve to force checks. Where is an ideal spot if any and why?

Answer (score 1):

I use a bit of everything you have suggested. I like to listen for the `$stateChangeStart` event like this taken directly from the docs:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ ... })
```

You can then use `event.preventDefault();` and **resolve** any http call before deciding what to do.

Interceptors are another option - just Google "Angularjs Interceptors" and I'm sure you will find a good example. However, while I only spent a limited time with Interceptors, I found that it was difficult to overcome the brief page glimpses that resulted when unauthenticated users would try and access a protected page.